# Flash CS5.5 actionscript capabilities

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is there something that timeline can do, and cannot be done with Actionscript-3?

Comment: The brush tool can easily be replicated in code to allow live drawing in your SWF.  The spray brush might be a real pain to code, but I bet there's a library out there somewhere.

Comment: Well, yeah. That was a light-hearted comment, of course :)

Comment: crash.  just kidding.  sort of...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything can be accomplished by code, one way or the other, in fact, the design mode stage in the IDE is Flash itself. However, there are several things that are hard to get done by code, the main one I can think of related to the timeline is shape tweening.

Comment: Do you mean the Flex design mode in Flash Builder? It's not quite clear. Anyway, yes, that is an embedded Flash thingy.

Comment: I meant the Flash Professional IDE.

Answer (score 1):

You can do everything that is possible on the timeline using pure ActionScript, but it can get quite complex.  Arranging complex animations is often easier using the IDE timeline, but if you want to move to a pure scripting solution I recommend looking at Greensock's [TweenMax](http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/) and [TimelineMax](http://www.greensock.com/timelinemax/) classes.  These are much easier to use than AS3's built in Tween class, and offer much more power, allowing you to tween any property of an object, and to sequence groups of tweens.

Answer (score 0):

Timeline can help non-programmers to make flash animation. It's harder for them to use as3. :)

Answer (score 0):

years ago i recall reading that Inverse Kinematics (Bone Tool) in Flash Professional is accomplished with behind-the-scenes XML and not so easily accomplished, if at all, with ActionScript.

Comment: I think you would use Box2D for that, although I never have myself.

Comment: absolutely, there are certainly ways to accomplish this is ActionScript.  i was just mentioning that adobe's implementation of IK isn't so readily available to developers outside of their tooling.